# Add string[] to List<string[]> c# .Net

Tags: c#

I have a `List<string[]> parsedData`.

I have another `List<string[]> newData = {n, 1, 2, 3}`.

The strings in `parsedData` seems to be stored the following way:

```
1. a b c
2. 1 2 3 
3. 1 2 3
```

Which is perfect. When I add the `newData` to `parsedData` it becomes like this:

```
1. a b c
2. 1 2 3
3. 1 2 3
4. n 1 2 3
```

I'm searching for a way to transpose the `newData` list and add it in a similar fashion but I have problem getting it to work. Can someone please shed some light on this matter.

This is the code when I parse parsedData:

```
List<string[]> parsedData = new List<string[]>();
        string[] fields;

        try
        {
            TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(path);
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            parser.SetDelimiters(",");

            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                fields = parser.ReadFields();
                for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (fields[i] == "NaN")
                        fields[i] = null;
                }
                parsedData.Add(fields);
            }

            parser.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }

        return parsedData;
```

The string[] newData is added to a list in this way:

```
List<string[]> newData = new List<string[]>();
        string[] mCol = mean.meanCol(c, parsedData); // function that returns a string[]
        newData.Add(mCol);
```

I then want to join the two lists as explained above so it looks like this:

1. a b c n
2. 1 2 3 1
3. 1 2 3 2
4. 1 2 3 3

Comment: What should the output look like. I don't really understand your problem...

Comment: What is the logic to get the fourth line of your desired output? -- and why do you declare `newData` as `List<string[]>` when later you use it like `string[]`? Is it really a `string[]`?

Comment: Mu data represents measurement data. The top row should contain the name of all channels while the columns cointains the measurement data.

Comment: Sounds more like a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` or, if you're more comfortable with it, a `Dictionary<string, string[]>`. With the key being the name of the channel and the value being the list/array of measurement data.

Comment: I use a list because it will grow depending on what the user do. The user is free to add any amount of string[] 's

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I *assume* you have a text file that looks something like this:

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

and after you read/parse it, you end up with something that is equal to:

```
List<string[]> parsedData = 
  new List<string[]> 
  { 
    new []{"a", "b", "c"},  
    new []{"1", "2", "3"},  
    new []{"1", "2", "3"}  
  };
```

and then you want to be able to add something like:

```
List<string[]> newData =
  new List<string[]>
  {
    new []{"n", "1", "2", "3"},  
    new []{"m", "1", "2", "3"},  
    // ... added more new data
  };
```

Well, first the `newData` is "turned" 90° and each item has one more data point than the existing ones (`a` has `1` and `1`, while `n` has `1`, `2` and `3`).

So even in the ideal way, you'd end up with:

```
List<string[]> combinedData = 
  new List<string[]> 
  { 
    new []{"a", "b", "c", "n", "m"},  
    new []{"1", "2", "3", "1", "1"},  
    new []{"1", "2", "3", "2", "2"},  
    new []{null, null, null, "3", "3"}  
  };
```

And second, you use `string[]` instead of `List<string>`, so growing is more complicated.

In any case, a `List<string[]>` is a suboptimal data structure to express what you want: having several channel names and being able to store several measurements per channel name.

I'd suggest a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, where the `key` is the channel name and the `value`, which is a `List<string>` contains the list of measurements for that channel name.

There are probably easier ways to do it, but one way to get from your `List<string[]>` to a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` could work like:

```
var transposedData = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
var minArrayLength = parsedData.Min(a => a.Length);
for (var index = 0; index < minArrayLength; index++)
{
  string key = null;
  foreach (var array in parsedData)
  {
    if (key == null)
    {
      key = array[index];
      transposedData[key] = new List<string>();
    }
    else
    {
      transposedData[key].Add(array[index]);
    }
  }
}
```

Btw. don't get confused by the [var keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb383973.aspx), I like to use that a lot.

Once you have it in this data structure, you can add your `newData` like this:

```
foreach (var array in newData)
{
  var key = array[0];
  transposedData[key] = new List<string>();

  // skip the key
  for (var index = 1; index < array.Length; index++)
  {
    transposedData[key].Add(array[index]);
  }
}
```

Now, the question is, are you happy with that, or do you really need a `List<string[]>` again? If so, you need to transpose it back. Maybe with something like this:

```
// using a list inside for now for easier adding
var backTranspose = new List<List<string>>();

// determine the max number of measurements for a channel name
var maxLength = transposedData.Values.Max(l => l.Count);

// use one more to include key
for (var valueIndex = 0; valueIndex <= maxLength; valueIndex++)
{
  backTranspose.Add(new List<string>());
}

foreach (var kvp in transposedData)
{
  var index = 0;
  backTranspose[index].Add(kvp.Key);

  for (var valueIndex = 0; valueIndex < maxLength; valueIndex++)
  {
    index++;
    if (kvp.Value.Count > valueIndex)
    {
      backTranspose[index].Add(kvp.Value[valueIndex]);
    }
    else
    {
      backTranspose[index].Add(null);
    }
  }
}

// turn the lists back into arrays
parsedData = new List<string[]>();
foreach (var list in backTranspose)
{
  parsedData.Add(list.ToArray());
}
```

One caveat though, a `Dictionary` is not ordered. So you might end up with channel names at different positions. But of course, the channel name and the corresponding measurement data will have the same index.

Comment: Corak, thank you for your efforts. I will consider this. In any case I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LINQ` and `Concat` to achieve what you need to do.

```
var allData = parsedData.Concat( newData ).ToList();
```

Comment: No, I've already tried this. newData is still a row at the end of the output file instead of a column to the furthest right.

Comment: As u edited ur post my answer is out of date as i suggested sth different. Now tit's clear what u want